# Sorting a tuple based on occurrence count

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list which contains tuples like

```
[('a','apple'),('a','ant'),('a','apple'),('b','banana')]
```

I want to sort based on first value like

```
[('a','apple','ant', 3),('b','banana', 1)]
```

I have tried separating the tuples and counting it but recombining them is too much hassle. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Your first example, is I believe, malformed.  You have 4 elements in the first tuple, and only 3 in the second, in a way that it seems it would be hard for you to work with the result. - also, you're not just "sorting".  You're doing something more, since you end up with fewer elements.

Comment: Can you open a separate question for "sorting based on first value"? That requires a much different solution than the other.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your question. Your question is at risk of being closed as too broad, otherwise.

Comment: @coldspeed I rolled back your edit because unfortunately I already spent time answering the first question.

Comment: @blhsing That is fine. Removing either would have worked. I would have deleted my answer, but I'm out of delete votes now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dict.fromkeys` method to remove duplicates while keeping the input order. If you're using Python 3.6 or earlier versions, use `collections.OrderedDict` in place of dict.

```
l = [('a','apple'),('a','ant'),('a','apple'),('b','banana')]
d = {}
for k, v in l:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print([(k, *dict.fromkeys(s), len(s)) for k, s in d.items()])
```

This outputs:

```
[('a', 'apple', 'ant', 3), ('b', 'banana', 1)]
```

If you're using Python versions before 3.5 where generic unpacking isn't supported, you would have to concatenate the tuples instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
l = [('a','apple'),('a','ant'),('a','apple'),('b','banana')]
d = {}
for k, v in l:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print([(k,) + tuple(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s)) + (len(s),) for k, s in d.items()])
```

Comment: at *dict.fromkeys I get invalid syntax

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Comment: The code requires Python 3.5 or later for generic unpacking. See demo: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/17bz

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example for earlier Python versions.